# Using GPU for easyocr

Tags: python, easyocr

When executing this code:

```
import easyocr

Reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
```

I get this warning:

```
CUDA not available - defaulting to CPU. Note: This module is much faster with a GPU.
```

I've already downloaded CUDA but it is quite complicated and I couldn't find a tutorial that fits my needs.

What can I do so that easyocr is using my GPU and not CPU?

(I'm new to stackoverflow so please don't be mad if the question is asked wrong. Thanks!)

Comment: The [website](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR) says that you need to install `pytorch` with CUDA here first: https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR#installation

Comment: Thanks! Now I know that I can't use CUDA with an Intel graphics card! But if I had the right GPU it should've worked.

Comment: Oh so you are using Intel graphics card? Yes that won't work because they support only NVIDIA cards (hence CUDA).

Comment: CUDA was created by Nvidia, so as long as you have an Nvidia GPU you should be okay https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA